# user cannot log on even after password reset

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, login

I have a user that cannot log on, even after reseting the password.

It allows the user to 'Change password at first log on' but then does not let the user log in. The only error that displays is the generic 'Wrong username or bad password' (Or words to that effect).

The only event logged on the server, again is just the generic 'Audit failure' for incorrect username or passwords.

Server: AD on Windows Server 2003

Client: XP SP3

Other users can log on with the same client.
The user cannot log onto any client.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was a stupid fault ...

In the user's properties -> account -> log on to ... was set to 'The following computers'.

I just changed it to 'All computers' and viola.

I'll look further into the errors, now that I know what caused it, and see if it does actually tell me that it is related to not being allowed to log onto a certain client.